# Add RSS auto-detection when using Zend Layout

Tags: php, zend-framework, rss

I've got a site using Zend Layouts and on certain pages I'd like to add RSS auto-detection (adding a <link> in the head section). How do I add this to the layout just on certain pages?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add to your view:

```
<? $this->headLink()->appendAlternate('/feed/', 'application/rss+xml', 'RSS Feed'); ?>
```

Add to your layout in `<head>`

```
<?= $this->headLink() ?>
```